# VB.NET Form.Show closes the application for unknown reason

Tags: vb.net, forms

VB.NET Framework 4.7.2
Visual Studio Community 2019 V16.11.2

I have a WinForms application and, for the most part, I start with a form to display the loading of datatables. This is handled in the Application Events module:

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.TheCompany) Then
                MainForm = FormConnection
            Else
                MainForm = FormDataLoad
            End If
        End Sub
```

When the datatables are all loaded the FormDataLoad has a close button which is enabled by the procedure which loads all the datatables:

```
        With FormDataLoad
            .ButtonClose.Visible = True
        End With
```

When the button is pressed it calls another form which displays various charts etc based on the datatables which have been loaded:

```
Private Sub ButtonClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub FormDataLoad_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
        With FormOverview
            .Show()
        End With
    End Sub
```

When FormOverview loads, its labels, charts etc are all initialised and drawn BUT, mysteriously, the form closes and the application ends. The Application Shutdown event is raised:

```
' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
        Private Sub MyApplication_Shutdown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
            MessageBox.Show("Closing the application for some unknown reason")
        End Sub
```

When this message box is displayed it means that the application has closed but not as a result of any unhandled exception. Nowhere in the project is there any code to call FormOverview.close so I am at a loss to understand what is happening.

The form load code is here:

```
Private Sub FormOverview_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    With Me

        'Set the form caption and back colour and font
        .Text = "Retail Management Hero Data Visualisation Overview"
        .BackColor = Color.GhostWhite
        .Font = U.BasicFontSmall

        'Add event handler for the DAL
        AddHandler D.ConnectionOpened, AddressOf Connected

        'Form level variables for the KPJs
        Dim ITO As String = ""
        Dim ATV As String = ""
        Dim CRR As String = ""
        Dim GMROI As String = ""
        Dim OOS As String = ""
        Dim StocksSales As String = ""

        With KPIData.Rows(0)
            Me.Text = My.Settings.TheCompany & " " & Me.Text
            ITO = .Item("ITO").ToString
            CRR = .Item("CRR").ToString
            ATV = "€" & .Item("ATV").ToString
            GMROI = "€" & .Item("GMROI").ToString
            OOS = .Item("OOSRatio").ToString
            StocksSales = .Item("StocksToSales").ToString
        End With

        For Each CTL As Control In .Controls
            If TypeOf CTL Is Label Then
                With CTL
                    If .Name.Contains("Value") Then
                        .Font = U.BasicFontSuperLarge
                        .BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    Else
                        .BackColor = U.Spurs
                        .ForeColor = Color.GhostWhite
                    End If

                End With

            End If
        Next

        With .LabelReportDate
            .Text = "Reports As Of " & ReportDate
        End With

        With .LabelATVValue
            .Text = U.DecimalToSuperSubFormat(ATV, True)
        End With

        With .LabelGMROIValue
            .Text = U.DecimalToSuperSubFormat(GMROI, True)
        End With

        With .LabelCRRValue
            .Text = U.DecimalToSuperSubFormat(CRR, True) & "%"
        End With

        With .LabelITOValue
            .Text = U.DecimalToSuperSubFormat(ITO, True)
        End With

        With .LabelOOSValue
            .Text = U.DecimalToSuperSubFormat(OOS, True) & "%"
        End With

        With .LabelStocksSalesValue
            .Text = U.DecimalToSuperSubFormat(StocksSales, True) & "%"
        End With

        'Extract the names of the X and Y axes
        Dim Xname As String = ""
        Dim Yname As String = ""

        With WineData
            Xname = .Columns("Department").ColumnName
            Yname = .Columns("Day").ColumnName
        End With

        'Draw the charts
        DrawColumnChart(WineData, .ChartWine, "Wine sales", Xname, Yname, 250, False)
        DrawColumnChart(OtherData, .ChartNonWine, "Other sales", Xname, Yname, 25, False)

        'Centre on the screen
        .CenterToScreen()
    End With
End Sub
```

So, what should happen is that this form displays centre screen with charts etc all displayed correctly.
If anyone has any ideas I would be most grateful.

Dermot

Answer (score 3):

I found out what was causing the problem.
In the Project's properties, in the `Application` tab, there Combo selector,  `Shutdown mode`.

The option I had selected was `When startup form closes` - by changing this to `When last form closes` the issue went away.

Like many problems, when you look at it too long you can't see the woods for the trees.